# How I can get data of preexisting database and show on the screen

Tags: sql, flutter, dart

i have little experience working with local databases in flutter. I have recently found huge amount of data in sql database from one apk file. Now I would like to use it on my own flutter, but i cannot get inner data. Could you show me how to do that. Thanks a lot beforehand. Any kind of help is appreaciated.

Comment: Can you read that data on your computer? If using mac, it has sqlite3 in-built command

Comment: Yes i can  via sql browser. But i cannot read it in flutter up by opening it